# Does 'virtual' mean real or fake?

Tags: meaning

> Our deputy manager is the virtual head of the business.

In this sentence the manager is the **real** person who in charge.

> There will be a virtual presenter and virtual guests who will help create the atmosphere of a beauty contest.

Here the presenter and guests are all **fake**.

This `virtual` really confuses me.

Comment: Have you read the [meanings of virtual](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/virtual?q=virtual) in a dictionary? Is there anything about this definition that you find unclear?

Comment: Essentially "virtual" means "not-real, but giving the impression of being real".

Comment: @MattЭллен in my English-Chinese dictionary it uses both `real` and `void` to describe `virtual`. Anyway thanks for the link, I will go through it.

Comment: "in my English-Chinese dictionary it uses both `real` and `void` to describe `virtual`."  That's key information, and it serves two purposes: (1) it lets others know that you've done some preliminary research, and (2) it helps others understand where your source of confusion is. It would be good advice to carefully include such clarifications into future questions if you continue to ask questions here at EL&U. Context (where you found these sentences) helps, too.  In general, questions which include such details are better received than those where the background information is scant.

Comment: Note "Virtually" gives the sentences almost opposite meaning. "Our deputy is virtually the head of the business" means he's not the designated head, but he does all the real work and is the head for all practical purposes except in the name.

Answer (score 6):

In both sentences, `virtual` means the same thing -- something that has the appearance and behavior of the real thing, but is not actually the real thing.

The "virtual head" of a business appears and acts as if he were the real head of the business. It is as if he were the head of the business, but he is not actually the head of the business.

The "virtual guests" appear and behave like real guests. It is as if they were real guests, but they are not actual guests.

Answer (score 4):

The concept *real* doesn't really apply. ***Virtual*** in these instances mean *effectively* but not *literally* or *formally*.

The deputy manager acts or serves as the head of the business even if someone else has the title.

The presenter and guests will be participating in the meeting by voice, image or text or a combination, but will not be physically present in the room.

In both cases there is a *reality* about the role or the involvement, there is just not a traditional *completeness* about the status or presence.

Answer (score 2):

In the first sentence your manager is not really the head of the business but rather a proxy.

The second sentence sounds more like maybe a [Max Headroom](http://youtu.be/IzxHDqUz8Sk) style presenter or actors pretending to be in a beauty contest to give the feel in some sort of open house. I would be able to elaborate better with the rest of the story.

Either way, ***Virtual*** is used the way it should be used in both cases and not contradictory.

Answer (score 0):

### virtual

*[Virtual](http://onelook.com/?w=virtual&ls=a)* means “*apparent*, but *not in fact*”. Sometimes it means “*not in fact* but *nearly so*”. Examples:

- *virtual* memory – *apparently* (to the program) but *not in fact* the physical memory of the machine
- *virtual* reality – *apparently* (to the observer) but *not in fact* physical reality; simulated reality
- *virtual* particle – an unobservable particle which might temporarily come into existence during a particle reaction; the possibility that it might exist briefly is necessary for the mathematics to correctly predict how particles behave, but will *never be demonstrated in fact* as a physical observation
- a *virtual* certainty – *not in fact* a complete certainty, but *nearly so*
- a *virtual* failure – *not in fact* a complete failure, but *nearly so*

### virtually

Similarly, the adverb form *[virtually](http://onelook.com/?w=virtually&ls=a)* can also mean either “*apparently*, but *not in fact*” or “*not in fact* but *nearly so*”. Examples:

- “Makes your dishes *virtually* spotless!” – makes your dishes *apparently* (or *nearly*), but *not in fact*, spotless (a classic bit of advertising hyperbole)
- *virtually* agree to something – *apparently* agree by not expressing disagreement, *without in fact* agreeing
- *virtually* present – *apparently* present (in virtual reality, or present by representative or proxy), but *not in fact* present
- *virtually* paralyzed – *not* paralyzed *in fact*, but *nearly so*

Comment: the example is very bad. The common usage of "Virtually" is almost antonymous to "virtual". While "virtual" is "in name only; not for real", "virtually" means "almost; not in the name, but for all practical purposes."

Comment: You can always replace "virtually" with "not" for improved honesty.  It just means they’re trying to hoodwink you.

Answer (score -1):

Virtual in your context, I believe, does mean fake. However, it is not just some fake, but it represents the idea of becoming as realistic as possible giving the observer the illusion that it is real. 
Hence, virtual is something fake that is nearly real.